# Can I use css-modules with LESS + nesting?

Tags: reactjs, less, webpack, css-modules

The [documentation on css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) is pretty sparse, so I'm not sure if I can do this or not.

[This article](http://glenmaddern.com/articles/css-modules) says the way I'd style a button with `normal` and `error` states would look like this:

```
.common { /* font-sizes, padding, border-radius */ }
.normal { composes: common; /* blue color, light blue background */ }
.error { composes: common; /* red color, light red background */ }
```

But I'd prefer to write it like this:

```
.common {
    /* font-sizes, padding, border-radius */
    &.normal { /* blue color, light blue background */ }
    &.error { /* red color, light red background */ }
}
```

Like I've always done, without introducing this new `composes` syntax. I think it's more clear which styles build on top of other styles if I can actually nest them in code.

But I don't know what this would be exported as by css-modules? The only examples they give are simple class name selectors. I have no idea what about `.common.normal` will be exported as, or what `.common > .normal ~ .strange`? Do I basically have to *not* use any kind of CSS selector if I use css-modules?

Comment: In thinking about this some more, I imagine only `common` would get exported, and I'd have to write my component like this: `<button class={[styles.common,'normal']}>Submit</button>`

Comment: Why not just tab out the `.normal {}` and `.error {}`?  Should still give the visual cue that these are related to `.common {}`.

Comment: @JasonTFeatheringham Yeah, that'd help, but reformatting would break it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also using less with css modules, but I don't think they way you are using the '&' fits with the goal of css modules. From my understanding 'composes' is more analogous to @import than &, and I only find myself using the & for psuedo-classes.

You can definitely do things the way you have here, but don't you find it a bit strange that you have to specify both the 'common' and 'normal' classes in the HTML? Much better in my opinion to just specify 'normal', and let normal inherit the shared styles using 'compose'.

Comment: You're right, I'd prefer not to specify both class names in the HTML. I suppose `composes` is more like a mixin, which needs to be written with more-or-less the same syntax anyway. I guess I'd prefer a new operator then so that I could nest them the way I'd like, but oh well. I'll try `composes`; maybe I'll get used to it :D Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 9):

```
.common {
    /* font-sizes, padding, border-radius */
    :global {
        &.normal { /* blue color, light blue background */ }
        &.error { /* red color, light red background */ }
    }
}
```

That's my solution. If you use `styles.common`, the css will be:

```
.ramdomStrings {
    /* I'm not sure if this exists, but it doesn't matter */
}
.ramdomStrings.normal { /* blue color, light blue background */ }
.randomStrings.error { /* red color, light red background */ }
```

Comment: `css-loader`  does not seem to like & LESS selector used in :global scope



Getting the following error on compile with Webpack 4 / css-loader 2.1.1

`Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):Error: Missing whitespace after :global`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a webpack loader for css-modules you can use the [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) loader and add various plugins to get your desired behaviour.

There is for example the "[postcss-nested](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-nested)" plugin, which allows you to write nested rules.